# templates with ui:insert-ui:composition doesn't work well

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use jsf facelets templates, using the components ui: insert
in the template and ui: composition in which they use it, my code is something like this:

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/Cabecera.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/StyleButton.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/Progreso.css"/>
        <title>Registro</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="left">
                <ui:insert name="left">Left</ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="left_content">
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the user:

```
<ui:composition template="./../Templeates/plantilla.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputText value="Registrar Nuevo Estudiante" style="font-size: 35px;font-weight: 100;color: #dce9f0"/>
        <h:form id = "formInput">
            <p:outputLabel for="codigo" value="Codigo "/>
            <p:chips id="codigo" label="codigo Estudiante" value="#{RegistroAsistencia.codigos}"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="formbutton" >
            <p:commandButton value="Añadir" icon="ui-icon-star" actionListener="#{RegistroAsistencia.agregarAsesoriaEstudiante()}" update=":formInput">
                <p:resetInput target=":formInput"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

in the managedbean I have something like

```
public List<String> getCodigos() {
        Logger.getLogger(ConsultaInformacionAsistentesBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "--->\n get codigos: "+codigos+"\n");
        return codigos;
    }

    public void setCodigos(List<String> codigos) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConsultaInformacionAsistentesBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "--->\nset codigos: "+codigos+"\n");
        this.codigos = codigos;
    }
```

I put the loggers to verify that the get and set methods are used respectively, when I use the "Añadir" button, the set request is never made, I verify it without using the template and in this it works:

```
get codes: null

set codes: null <-- When pressing the button

set codes: [2135494]
```

but when i try using the template:

```
get codigos: null

nothing <-- When pressing the button

get codigos: null
```

And in the agregarAsesoriaEstudiante method, codigos is null.

In conclusion, if I use the template, the "set" method of the elements is never used, so in the managedBean they are null and I am unable to get the input, try other elements of PrimeFaces different to p:chips like p: inputText but I did not find a solution , exactly the same code without using the template works perfectly, it is possible that I need something in the code or there is an error if someone knows or had similar problems I would appreciate it if I shared it.

Comment: I cannot imagine the same construct with two forms works (differently) when not using a template. Since the logging from the one with templates is exactly what I'd expect. Sure you don't have just one form in the non-template version?

Comment: I believe the problem in your code is the usage of twi sepparate forms. Merge them in just one form and it should work.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the sepparate forms, thanks.